# Internal server error

Tags: migration, internal-server-error

I designed 2 Wordpress sites, one was inside another which you can get to by calling the folder where the second installation is.
The first person that started the design used the first installation (www.example.com) as a coming soon page while he used the second (www.example.com/mainsite) for the design of the main website. He started it this way before he left the job for me to finish. I finished designing at .../mainsite and was supposed to move to it to the main website @ www.example.com.

I deleted all the initial database tables from (example.com) and imported tables from (example.com/mainsite) to its own database @ (example.com). I also used a text editor to change all the URL from (example.com/mainsite) to (example.com) so as to avoid any error. I then moved the mainsite folder to (example.com) root directory after deleting the original directory files that had the maintenance installation. And then finished it off by changing the database details to (example.com) details to avoid database connection errors.

After all these, I tried accessing the website at example.com but could only load the home page and the admin area. Any other page that I tried loading shows me an internal server error.

Please how can I fixe this. Is there something that I did wrong with my procedures? Please any help would be much appreciated. Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `www.example.com/site1` is the 1st site (in the root folder `site1` folder), and `www.example.com/site2` is the second site (in the root folder `site2` folder. The easiest way (normally) to clone (or move) a site is to use the excellent WP-Clone plugin to backup and restore the 'site1' site to the root. But, you will have problems accessing `site2` (which is a separate WP installation, as I understand), because the normal htaccess file used in WP sites will think site2 is part of site1.

So you would need to do some `htaccess` work to get `www.example.com` to point to the site1 folder, and `www.example.com/site2` to point to the site2 folder. That might be a bit complex to do, though.

So, I'd recommend that you set up a multisite installation. The primary site would be in the `www.example.com` root folder, and then site2 would be `www.example.com/site2` . This might be the best solution, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you. I think I need some tutorials on htaccess. Can you suggest where I can find some?

Comment: There's lots of tutorials via the googles - try this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=htaccess+tut&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 .
But I think you'd be better off with a multisite installation, subdirectory-based. Figuring out htaccess is not for the 'faint of heart'.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I think a knowledge of htaccess will help for subsequent challenges that require its assistance.